# Getting a Reflector error Assembly Not Found when installing CruiseControl.NET

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I see an entry in ccnet.exe.config

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NetReflector" publicKeyToken="2f4dd8b32acbcd8e" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.120" newVersion="1.1.2009.1004" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

When I first installed the service, I had no errors, but after following this tutorial 
[link text](http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/06/01/cruisecontrolnet-tutorial-part-1/)

I am getting this error when I try to run the service or CCValidator. 
Could not load file or assembly 'NetReflector, Version=1.1.2009.1004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dbcd6104b72f39b2' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1):

There was issue with cc.net 1.4.4 and the vsts plugin where I had to compile the plugin from source against the netreflector version 1.1.
However this issue has been fixed. Just install the latest version of cc.net, 1.4.4.83 (i.e. 1.4.4 SP1) and use the ccnet.vsts.plugin.dll 1.3.1.
I would use backup the ccnet.config and then just unzip on top
[Get the binary zip distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/CruiseControl.NET%201.4.4%20SP1/CruiseControl.NET-1.4.4.83.zip/download)